# How to display Numeric Keypaid using phonegap application on below Android version 2.3

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a mobile application using Phonegap framework and it has some HTML input elements in it, like this:

```
<input name="txtPinCode" id="txtPinCode" placeholder="Pin Code" maxlength="20" value="" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*">
```

When i open application and touch or click input text this tag proper working on above Android 4.0 version but same tag not working android 2.3 version.

Please help me.

Comment: I am using this Html tag <input name="txtPinCode" id="txtPinCode" placeholder="Pin Code" maxlength="20" value="" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*">

Comment: i am all ready tried its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `type="number"` not supported in below Android 2.3

[Reference link](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/)